# How to decode public key from a transaction signed by private key using web3j?

Tags: java, encryption, ethereum, web3-java

I want to verify if a transaction is signed by the specific user. So i want to decode the public key from transaction and compare it.

As seen in the code below, i encoded and signed a transaction using my credential.
But it seems that the public key decoded from tx is different from my credential.

[image]

Comment: See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17708/solidity-ecrecover-and-web3j-sign-signmessage-are-not-compatible-is-it